# z3py: How to implement a counter in z3?

Tags: counter, z3, smt, z3py

I want to design logics similar to a counter in Z3py.

If writing python script, we usually define a variable "counter" and then keep incrementing it when necessary. However, in Z3, there is no variant. Therefore, instead of defining an variant, I define a trace of that variant.

This is a sample code. Suppose there is an array "myArray" of size 5, and the elements in the array are 1 or 2. I want to assert a constraint that there must be two '2's in "myArray"

```
from z3 import *

s = Solver()
myArray = IntVector('myArray',5)
for i in range(5):
    s.add(Or(myArray[i]==1,myArray[i]==2))
counterTrace = IntVector('counterTrace',6)
s.add(counterTrace[0]==0)
for i in range(5):
    s.add(If(myArray[i]==2,counterTrace[i+1]==counterTrace[i]+1,counterTrace[i+1]==counterTrace[i]))
s.add(counterTrace[5]==2)
print s.check()
print s.model()
```

My question is that is this an efficient way of implementing the concept of counter in Z3? In my real problem, which is more complicated, this is really inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this but it is much easier to create the sum over `myArray[i] == 2 ? 1 : 0`. That way you don't need to assert anything and you are dealing with normal expressions.

Comment: You are right, but I worry more about the efficiency, or in other words, short checking time. The complexity of my implementation is O(n), where n is the length of the array. In my real problem, where I loop through the array twice, the complexity becomes O(n^2), which is really inefficient.

Comment: So the real problem is the quadratic complexity right? Then this has nothing to do with counting. In this light the question seems irrelevant to your problem?! @Z.Jin

Comment: I guess I should rephrase my question: is there another way to a set a constraint to a variant in addition to setting a constraint to its trace in z3? The trace idea is working but seems inefficient to me because it adds a lot more variables and constraints.

Comment: Everything is immutable in Z3. I'm unclear on why the trace idea seems wrong to you. It adds a linear amount of variables. Each variable must be ceil(log2(n)) bits in size so you could argue that the amount of work required is n*log(n), yes.; In the literature there is the idea of using counting networks to efficiently encode constraints such as "count of something must be between x and y". This does help solver performance. Z3 has some support for it in the form of a tactic. I'm unfamiliar with that.